# Why does Cordova ios Vue component only display on reloading app after migrating to WKWebview?

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

The bottom div of buttons on my app don’t show on first loading up but then do when the app is swiped away and then reselected.

Console log messages when app first loads are:

```
    2021-02-01 10:55:11.982756+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] Apache Cordova native platform version 5.1.1 
is starting.
2021-02-01 10:55:11.982849+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2021-02-01 10:55:12.341036+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process 
SoundSleep
    2021-02-01 10:55:12.341149+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2021-02-01 10:55:12.341261+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2021-02-01 10:55:12.392665+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2021-02-01 10:55:12.392716+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2021-02-01 10:55:12.394914+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if 
required on resume
2021-02-01 10:55:12.394987+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] Using WKWebView
2021-02-01 10:55:12.395228+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][console] 0.052929ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.395373+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.057101ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.396933+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.510978ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.397027+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.038981ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.402787+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [Crashlytics] Version 3.10.1 (129)
2021-02-01 10:55:12.413614+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][fabricplugin] 16.546965ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.415830+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][file] 2.138019ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.417003+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][localnotification] 1.132011ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.417043+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][localnotification] 0.003934ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.419718+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 2.645016ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.420720+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 0.934958ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.420776+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] CDVPlugin class WKWebViewXHRFix (pluginName: 
wkwebviewxhrfix) does not exist.
2021-02-01 10:55:12.420804+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][wkwebviewxhrfix] 0.038981ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.420856+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][inappbrowser] 0.029087ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.420889+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] CDVPlugin class CDVUIInAppBrowser (pluginName: 
uiinappbrowser) does not exist.
2021-02-01 10:55:12.420912+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][uiinappbrowser] 0.030041ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.420965+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][wkinappbrowser] 0.033021ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.421067+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 25.961995ms
2021-02-01 10:55:12.747924+0000 SoundSleep[287:9375] IAB.close() called but it was already closed.
```

When the app does reload and the div displays ok I see these console log messages added:

```
2021-01-29 12:43:36.109629+0000 SoundSleep[488:66151] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView::
2021-01-29 12:43:36.109695+0000 SoundSleep[488:66151] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView title: snore.app
2021-01-29 12:43:36.109723+0000 SoundSleep[488:66151] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView location: file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3FFF7BB5-2C15-4649-8997-94993B7E5677/SoundSleep.app/www/dist/index.html#/reports
2021-01-29 12:43:36.109747+0000 SoundSleep[488:66151] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView reload: 0
```

I tried the upgrade of cordova ios platform from 4.5.5 to 5.1.1 and cordova inappbrowser 3.1.0 to 3.2.0
And added

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

to config.xml
Also added a patch

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix.
```

I also tried an upgrade of cordova ios platform from 4.5.5 to 6.1.1 and cordova inappbrowser 3.1.0 to 4.1.0 but got the same results.

Any kind person able to help me resolve this issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found workaround:

Add to main.scss or wherever your html, body code is located:

```
html, body {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
}
```

See apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine: Issue #108 and https://forum.framework7.io/t/ios-wkwebview-blank-space-at-the-bottom/8530